# Using nested FOR loop for printing square by numbers

Tags: java

I'm trying to print square by using nested for loop. It is needed square to look like sequence numbers. Actually I didn't receive square. Please see attached file to understand my goal- red border.

```
public class Day22022014 {

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=in.nextInt();

for(int row=1; row<=n; row++){
System.out.printf("%d %n", row);

    for(int col=row; col<2*n; col++){
        System.out.printf("%d ", col);

    }

    }}}
```

[image: source code]

Comment: Have u tried anything ?

Comment: Include code **as code**, not as a picture. The question is meant to be useful to others in the future, not just to you now, and external links rot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few errors there. The first `printf` is incorrectly outputting a number, you only need to make a new line, all numbers should be outputted inside the inner `for`.

Secondly, the condition `col < 2 * n` is wrong, you only want to go up to `row + n - 1`.

I suggest you go through this and try to understand, how do the indices `row` and `col` change in each iteration.

```
for(int row = 1; row <= n; row++){
    for(int col = row; col <= (row + n - 1); col++){
        System.out.printf("%d ", col);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```